# Cannot deserialize type with interface

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

The below code snippet tries to serialize an item and de-serialize using it is interface.
Please give an explanation how I can deserialize types inherited from the interface like on example

```
class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {
 Item item = new Item { A = 123321 };

 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
 Serializer.Serialize(ms  item);
 ms.Position = 0;
 Serializer.Deserialize<IItem>(ms);
 }
 }
}


ProtoInclude(100  typeof(Item))
public interface IItem
{
 int A { get; set; }
}

public class Item : IItem
{
 ProtoMember(1)
 public int A { get; set; }
}
```

Raise an error:

> ```
> The type can't be Updated once a serializer has been produced for test.Item >(test.IItem)
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(Type type  Boolean demand  Boolean getBaseKey) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 388
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKeyImpl(Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 362
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.GetKey(Type& type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 982
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader  Type type  Object value  Boolean noAutoCreate) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 576
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source  Object value  Type type  SerializationContext context) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 506
> at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source  Object value  Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 488
> at ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeserializeT(Stream source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 69
> at test.Program.Main() in ...
> ```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the Problem is... You have to recreate the serializer for the IItem Type. Besides, are you sure that Protobuf is able to deal with Interfaces?

Comment: Why don't people read the exceptions! 9 times out of 10 it contains all the information you need....

Comment: Usage of Serializer does not assume creation or re-creation of serializer for specific type - it is implemented as a static method in static class.

Comment: I really don't think this deserved downvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, at the current time, interface support works for properties / lists, etc - but does **not** work for the root object. So you would need a concrete root type. Other than that - it is *basically* there - I moved the `ProtoMember(1)` to the interface, which feels more natural - but:

```
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Item item = new Item { A = 123321 }; 

        var obj = new Wrapper { Item = item };
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            IItem iObj = Serializer.Deserialize<Wrapper>(ms).Item;
            Item cObj = (Item)iObj;
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
class Wrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IItem Item { get;set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Item))]
public interface IItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    int A { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Item : IItem
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```